# SQL Server: I need to write syntax that will insert a dynamic header above my first line of data

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 18: I need to add syntax that will insert a header line above the first line of data. The required header fields are:

1. a file identifier (fixed text)
2. the total number of employees listed (variable),
3. The sum of the reimbursement amounts listed (variable)
4. the date the data was generated (variable).

Ideally, the header line would appear as row 1 of the data as I am using the syntax in a data-generating application that needs to (and does) excluded the column headings. These are the requirements of a flat-file upload process that must be automatic. Unfortunately, although the application we are using to generate the text-delimited file allows for column headings to be omitted, it does not include a header line feature. Suggestions?

The data includes the employee's company ID, the datetime stamp of when this specific data was pulled, the employee's weekly expense reimbursement amount, the employee's name, today's date, and the reason for the reimbursement.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 18. The latest is version 15; AKA SQL Server 2019.

Comment: As for the question, don't do this; your column names are your "header". When you extract the data into your presentation layer if you display the column names, you have a natural header "row".

Comment: This is only possible in a single query if the header line has the same fields and data types as query. Can you confirm this is true? If it's not true (and really, even if it is), this works is almost always better handled in the client code or reporting tool anyway.

Comment: This is much better handled on the client side. Dump the header info into the file first, followed by the data

Comment: Larnu, the General tab under Properties lists the name as Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.5.1, but the version of each component is listed with a component-specific version of 15 or lower. I thank you for your comment - it drove me to have a better understanding of the version numbering system. To your second point, the requirements of our vender are: 1) No column headers, and 2) a header line with specific data.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
declare @colheader varchar(200);
set @colheader = ' '+'Fixed text '; -- you need a blank so this row floats to the top
declare @rows int;
select @rows = count(*) from table1;
set @colheader += ' Number of rows:'+cast(@rows as varchar);
```

-- do same for 3 and 4

Then

```
select @colheader
union
select col1  from table
```

Comment: That doesn't guarantee the ordering, and `union` implies `distinct`, which is probably undesirable, you want `union all` instead

Comment: union all just guarantees all the rows from both sets which is not an issue here.

Comment: No, if there are multiple identical rows they will be merged if you use `union`

Comment: I create a single unique row that is unioned with many rows. Where are the multiple identical rows coming from?

Comment: `union` implies `distinct` so it's as if you wrote `select distinct @colheader union all select distinct col1  from table` there may be multiple identical rows in `table`

Comment: I can't keep engaging in this. Where are the duplicate rows coming from? @colheader is one distinct row which is not contained in table. Table may have dups but the person who posed the question did not say that was a possibility.